# What does this operator ~= mean in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this `$("a[rel~='single']")` somewhere. What is the operator `~=` in jquery?

Does anyone know where the documentation for that is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Comment: All of the docs can be found at api.jquery.com. [There's even a search function.](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=~%3D&go=) (although the current question could've been answered by looking at the only match in a "find in document" search for `~=` at the index page.)

Comment: 7 downvotes? Seems like a valid question to me

Comment: Alright, When i google ~=, it returns nothing.. anyway thanks guys. All I want is the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When the equal sign in an attribute selector is preceded by a tilde (
>   ~ ), that means that the selector will match if the value listed is
>   any one of the space-separated values of the given attribute. So the
>   first rule's selector, *[class~="urgent"] , will match any of the
>   following elements:

```
<p class="very urgent really">
<table class="urgent">
<ul class="not urgent">
<pre class="not terribly urgent but still worth knowing">
```

Source: http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200008b.html

---

jQuery documentation for the tilde selector can be found here:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Answer (score 2):

[Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

This selector matches the test string against each word in the attribute value, where a "word" is defined as a string delimited by whitespace. The selector matches if the test string is exactly equal to any of the words.

Answer (score 2):

it is a "attribute contains word" selector. It means that $("a[rel~='single']") will select every  tag containing the "single" word in the rel attribute.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces.
See:: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Comes under attribute. jQuery custom attribute selector.
**attribute-contains-word-selector**

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/